# How to keep rsync over SSH connection permanent - no broken pipe

Tags: ssh, rsync

I try to run a rsync on a shared server that I have no control over the ssh-config file to prevent the broken pipe error because the connection drop.

Here's a snippet of the code I use to backup

```
rsync -avz --blocking-io --delete-after --exclude 'mail*' /home user@remote:./backup/monthly/
```

Using this works fine for around 10min. , the the broken pipe error appears to tell me I've lost connection... probably because the rsync run in an idle state over SSH so SSH thinks I don't do anything while the rsync is running.

I've tried with and without --blocking-io but the connection still drop. Are they any trick to keep the SSH session alive until the rsync is complete **without having access to the ssh-config file**?

Answer (score 3):

This works providing your running OpenSSH.

Edit your `~/.ssh/config` file and add the following to activate the keep-alive system for just your user for all host connected to.

If you want to do this just for one host, switch the `*` with a host name of your choosing.

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 300
    ServerAliveCountMax 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the parameter 'ServerAliveInterval' as below:

```
rsync -avzhe 'ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60' local/dir/files your_user@remote:/destination/
```

Comment: Use:    rsync -e "ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60"       instead of:       rsync 'ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60'